# Javascript For Loop + Submit Button

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop, submit

I am trying to display a check box with 5 items. When the user clicks these items and hits submit, the total with the tax rate included will appear. My problem is that the submit box does not seem to work.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <!--
      JavaScript 6th Edition  v 1.16

      Filename: page 2.html
   -->
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0">
   <title>Hedgie Heroes: Shop</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-device-width: 999px)" href="projhand.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1000px)" href="project.css" />
 
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css">
   <script src="modernizr.custom.05819.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="container">
      <header>
         <h1>
            <img src="https://cdn.gomix.com/d593761a-2c9a-4565-9104-09aad9e28c12%2FHedgehog.png" width="200"  />
         </h1>
      </header>

      <nav>
         <ul>
        <!--
        Reminder:Add new page by first creating the html file. 
        Then adjust the id and href below to allow correct navigation.
        -->
            <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li id="currentpage"><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li id="page3"><a href="page3.html">Hedgehog Care</a></li>
            <li id="page4"><a href="page4.html">About Us</a></li>      </ul>
      </nav>
        
      <article>
         <h2>The Starter Kit Necessities!</h2>
        <br>
         <p>The options below is a list of recommended supplies for your Hedgehog! All supplies come with free treats and the opportunity to sign up for the Hedgie Club!</p>
        <br>
        <!--
        Everything below is for the products listed.
        <br> is implemented for page design and line breaks.
        -->       
      <form>
         <input type="checkbox" id="item1" value="24.00" />
         <label for="item1">Silent Running Wheel ($24.00)</label>
        <br>
         <input type="checkbox" id="item2" value="8.00" />
         <label for="item2">Food and Water Dish ($8.00)</label>
        <br>
         <input type="checkbox" id="item3" value="12.00" />
         <label for="item3">Snuggle Sack ($12.00)</label>
        <br>
         <input type="checkbox" id="item4" value="10.00" />
         <label for="item4">Hedgehog Food ($10.00)</label>
        <br>
         <input type="checkbox" id="item5" value="13.00" />
         <label for="item5">Igloo ($13.00)</label>
        <br>
         <input type="button" value="Submit" id="sButton" />
      </form>
        
      <br> <br> <br> <br>
      <p> **Note** All colored products are gender neutral. </p>
        
        
      </article>
    
      
     function calcTotal() 
      {
          var itemTotal = 0;
          var salesTaxRate = .06; //stores the curent sales tax
          var items = document.getElementByTagName("input");
          for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
            if(items[i].checked) {
                itemTotal += (items[i].value * 1);
            }
          }
          itemTotal *= 1+ salesTaxRate; //notice the use of the compound operator here
          document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Your order total is $" + itemTotal.toFixed(2);
}

      //add backward compatible event listener to Submit button
        var submitButton = document.getElementById ("sButton");
        if(submitButton.addEventListener) {
          submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false);
        } else if (submitButton.attachEvent)  {
          submitButton.attatchEvent("onclick", calcTotal)
        }
     
</script>
     
      <footer>
         <p>Hedgie Heroes &bull; Salisbury, Maryland</p>
      </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just use `onclick="calcTotal()"` in your button code

Answer (score 0):

You can use onclick event as below

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="sButton" onclick="calcTotal()" />
```

to call the js function **calcTotal()**

Comment: I will give it a try later when I get back on. I will keep you updated. I have been going crazy over this.

Comment: Ok, If you can create a code pen, i can also look in to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issue

- Instead of 'document.getElementByTagName("input")' use
  'document.getElementsByTagName("input")'
- Missing element with Id
  "total"

Also its better that you are adding the submit event through "addEventListener" rather than "onclick" because this will avoid potential CSRF attacks.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I still cannot get the darn thing to work. As for the missing element, how should I go about that. In the example i am following, it seems to work fine. Will I have to call it somewhere else? Sorry I feel like I am overthinking this.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do but for making the code work you will need an empty div or any container element and make the id as "total". This is after resolving the first point.

Comment: Here is a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/sreejithsekhar/ehp62qmk/

Answer (score 0):

I did reproduce this issue here and fixed. Here's how it should work:

Hedgie Heroes: Shop

```
  <header>

     <h1>

        <img src="1.png" width="200"  />

     </h1>

  </header>



  <nav>

     <ul>

    <!--

    Reminder:Add new page by first creating the html file. 

    Then adjust the id and href below to allow correct navigation.


    -->

        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

        <li id="currentpage"><a href="#">Products</a></li>

        <li id="page3"><a href="page3.html">Hedgehog Care</a></li>


        <li id="page4"><a href="page4.html">About Us</a></li>      </ul>

  </nav>

    
  <article>

     <h2>The Starter Kit Necessities!</h2>

    <br>

     <p>The options below is a list of recommended supplies for your Hedgehog! All
```

supplies come with free treats and the opportunity to sign up for the Hedgie Club!

```
    <br>

    <!--

    Everything below is for the products listed.

    <br> is implemented for page design and line breaks.

    -->       

  <form>

     <input type="checkbox" id="item1" value="24.00" />

     <label for="item1">Silent Running Wheel ($24.00)</label>

    <br>

     <input type="checkbox" id="item2" value="8.00" />

     <label for="item2">Food and Water Dish ($8.00)</label>

    <br>

     <input type="checkbox" id="item3" value="12.00" />

     <label for="item3">Snuggle Sack ($12.00)</label>

    <br>

     <input type="checkbox" id="item4" value="10.00" />

     <label for="item4">Hedgehog Food ($10.00)</label>

    <br>

     <input type="checkbox" id="item5" value="13.00" />

     <label for="item5">Igloo ($13.00)</label>


    <br>

     <input type="button" value="Submit" id="sButton" onclick="calcTotal()" />

       <div id="total">total </div>

  </form>

    

    
    
  </article>

  
<script>
  
 function calcTotal()
```

{

```
 var itemTotal = 0;
 
 var salesTaxRate = .06; //stores the curent sales tax
 
 var items = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
 
    if(items[i].checked) {
 
       itemTotal += (items[i].value * 1)

        

        
 
   }
 
 }
 
 itemTotal *= 1+ salesTaxRate; //notice the use of the compound operator here
 



 document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = "Your order total is $" +
```

itemTotal.toFixed(2);

}

```
  //add backward compatible event listener to Submit button

    var submitButton = document.getElementById ("sButton");

    if(submitButton.addEventListener) {

      submitButton.addEventListener("click", calcTotal, false);

    } else if (submitButton.attachEvent)  {

      submitButton.attatchEvent("onclick", calcTotal)

    }
```